# Getting ID from the Parent table using function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel to build an application. 
I have a model for the table courses `Course`. It has `id` and `code` both unique.

Sometimes, I'm passing the `code` to verify somethings. But always I have to get the `id` for that course using the `code`.

I wrote a function in the `Course` model.

```
public function getCourseId($code){
    return Course::where('code', $code)->pluck('id');
}
```

But when I try to call the function I don't have an object of this class. I just have `code` which is a column of the table `courses`

I tried to call `$code->getCourseId($code);`

But I know it's not right. Is there any other way to call this function with just `$code` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the helper function has to be static since you don't want to have to call it on an instance of `Course`. Try this:

```
public static function getCourseId($code){
    $course = static::where('code', $code)->first();
    if($course == null){
        return null;
    }
    return $course->id;
}
```

And call it like that:

```
$id = Course::getCourseId($code);
```

Also, in my opinion, this name would fit better:

```
$id = Course::getIdByCode($code);
```

Comment: Hopefully, will meet again with the next question if I have any :)

Comment: haha maybe ;) I'll be watching the laravel tag... however now I gotta catch some sleep.

Comment: Sup! Catch ya later ;)